# Rails how should the model/database be like when using the CanCan gem for Authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using devise as authorization. And are wondering how the model and database should be. In this ailscasts episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan says Ryan that he is using a many to many between roles and users.

My User model:'

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to :roles
has_many :posts
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My Role model:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to :users
end
```

But how should the roles table be like?

I was thinking creating the role table like:

```
id
admin - Boolean
moderator - Boolean
author - Boolean
```

And then the table roles_users:

```
id 
role_id
user_id
```

But why should a user have many roles? When having booleans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roles table would just be:

```
id
role_name
```

That way you can add roles without changing schema.